# excel conditional formatting | visualization of marginal return

Tags: conditional-formatting

I would like to visualize the marginal return of sets of data with conditional formatting, as shown in the 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmOXN.png). ([detailed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBE5.png))

I tried relative reference under R1C1,  by inputing the formula:

> RC - RC[-1] = 1 (or 2, 3, ..., 9)

and filling a corresponding color, but it didn't work out.

Please help and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will colour the row "combine". The code assumes that the colour palette code is between column `B` and `K`. The rest of the parameters is dynamic which you can set by yourself in the first part of the code.

It will create 2 Arrays of the Data range. Then it will compare the Arrays and write the differences in excel (Marginal Return in your example). The Marginal Return will also be stored as an Array.

Last step is to compare the Marginal Return Array with the Colour Palette Index. If the numbers match, it will copy the colour from the Palette to the Combine row for the marginal return value it should represent.

[image]

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub ColourValueDifferences()
Dim DataArray As Variant
Dim DataSubtractArray As Variant
Dim ColourArray As Variant
Dim MargRetArray() As Variant
Dim lcol As Integer
Dim fcol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim ColourRow As Integer
Dim ColourColumn As Integer

'############### SET THE DATA PARAMETERS ###############
lcol = Cells(1, "N").Column 'Set last row
'lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Use this instead to find the last column
fcol = Cells(1, "B").Column 'Set the first column in Data Range
ColourRow = Cells(6, "B").Row 'Set which row the Colour Palette will be located. It assumes that the palette always is between column B to K

'############### CREATE THE DATA RANGES ###############
    ColourArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(ColourRow, 2), Cells(ColourRow, 11)) 'Definie the range where colour scheme is
    ColourArray = Application.Index(ColourArray, 1, 0) 'Make the Array 1-Dimensional
    DataArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, fcol), Cells(1, lcol)) 'Create Array from Range to Create DataArray
    DataArray = Application.Index(DataArray, 1, 0) '
    DataSubtractArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, fcol + 1), Cells(1, lcol + 1)) '
    DataSubtractArray = Application.Index(DataSubtractArray, 1, 0)
    DataSubtractArray(lcol - 1) = 0 'Set last element in Array to 0

'############### CREATE THE MARGINAL RETURN VALUES ###############
    For i = LBound(DataArray) To UBound(DataArray)
        ReDim Preserve MargRetArray(i) 'Since we don't know the size of your final Array, we need to resize it
            MargRetArray(i) = DataSubtractArray(i) - DataArray(i)
    Next
    MargRetArray(0) = "" 'Remove the first value
    MargRetArray(i - 1) = "" 'Remove the last value

'############### PRINT THE DATA AND THE MARGINAL RETURN VALUES IN EXCEL ###############
    Range(Cells(2, fcol), Cells(2, lcol)) = MargRetArray 'Print the Marginal Return
    Range(Cells(1, fcol), Cells(1, lcol)).Offset(3, 0).Value = Range(Cells(1, fcol), Cells(1, lcol)).Value 'Copy Data Range To, where 3 is how many rows below the original dataset.

'############### PRINT THE DATA AND THE MARGINAL RETURN VALUES IN EXCEL ###############
    For j = LBound(MargRetArray) To UBound(MargRetArray) 'Loop through the Marginal Return Array (the difference values)
        ColourColumn = j + 2
        For k = LBound(ColourArray) To UBound(ColourArray) 'For every index value in MargRetArray, loop through the ColourArray values
            If MargRetArray(j) = ColourArray(k) Then 'If MarginalReturn value = Colour Array value, then copy the colour to the
                Cells(4, ColourColumn).Interior.Color = Cells(6, k + 1).Interior.Color 'Copy colour from the palette number to the combine row
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub
```